# Fixed Facebook user ID for your login system

Tags: javascript, php, facebook-graph-api, userid

I am building a login system that depends on Facebook login plugin (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web). Everything is going well with  this easy to use plugin. The bad news is that: today, I noted that the Facebook changes its user IDs, and these changes can deceive your login system.

Explaining the process and the problem:
1- The user goes to your website and click Facebook login button to access to your website. 
2- The plugin grabs the user's information from Facebook API, including the user Facebook ID.
3- Your script uses the grabbed info to check  your database, looking for the Facebook ID in the users table.
4- If the Facebook ID exists, the system allows the user to login. If it does not exist, the system creates a new account for the user and login him/her to your website. 
So, the same Facebook user might be registered more than one time as long as the Facebook changes the user's ID.

As I noted today:  Sometimes, the Facebook gives its user an ID with 9 digits, and other times give the user an ID with 19 digits. If you used any of those IDs; it would redirect you to the same user's profile. For example: if the user's IDs are 999999999 and 1010101010101010101 
https://facebook.com/999999999 and https://facebook.com/1010101010101010101 both URLs will lead you to same profile.

P.S. The script checks with the user's email, however the user has the choice not to supply his/her email address to your website.
I use API v2.*. I didn't use the old version (v1.*). So, I think this is not the issue of chronicle or app scoped IDs.

If you have any ideas that help in getting a fixed Facebook user ID, please let me know.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you actually prove that Facebook suddenly changed the ID's, with for example a link to any sort of documentation from facebook saying as much? I'm guessing the issue is on your end.

Comment: @adeneo the only prove I have is that the user account (ID) I use to test the application. I looked for Facebook documentations but I didn't find any documentations regarding this issue. I can send you (not publicly) 2 IDs for the same user. I got those IDs while I use the same Facebook app and the same Facebook API version. Therefore I thought the issue might not be on my end. – weblover just now   edit

Comment: facebook does not change the IDs. are you using different apps? do you know about "app scoped ids"? do you always get the ID with the /me endpoint? i am pretty sure it IS an issue with app scoped (and global) IDs.

Comment: @luschn I hope that I am wrong and the problem to be my end. No I don't use different apps, I get the id with facebook SDK by: $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email');

Comment: ok, and how do you get the other (different) id? the same api call with the same user access token will definitely give you the same one.

Comment: @luschn Because I am in the developing process now, I test with my own Facebook account, I get the user information including the user ID (with the same app, and the same api version), I store them in the users table in the database. Sometimes I empty the table. While I am doing this noted that I got 2 user IDs for the same user (me). If you want to see the 2 IDs I can send them to you in private, because I don't want to make my profile public.

Comment: ids are not really something you need to protect, especially if they are yours. anyway, if you use the exact same code with the same app and the same user token, then there should be no different ID. if that is really the case, you should try to somehow reproduce it, to create a bug report. but honestly, i highly doubt it.

Comment: @luschn You made me rethink about the conclusions. I will make more tests, may be I did something wrong. Thank you for your time and concern.